# Recursion using OCaml and unzip

Tags: list, recursion, functional-programming, ocaml

I did pattern matching, and it's working just fine:

```
let rec unzip  l = 
    match l with
    |[] -> ([], [])
    |(x,y)::tail -> 
    let (first, second) = unzip tail in 
      (x::first, y::second)
```

but how would I do this using map or fold right (tips only please don't tell me how to actually do it)

I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
let unzip : ('a * 'b) list -> 'a list * 'b list = let (first,second) = map (fun (x,y) -> (x::first, y::second) );;
```

but getting syntax error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the type of `List.map`:

```
# List.map;;
- : ('a -> 'b) -> 'a list -> 'b list = <fun>
```

You'll see that it always returns a list. Since you want to return a pair of lists, you can't use `List.map`. You can use a fold. Or you could call `List.map` once for each list in the pair.

**Update**

Let's just work with `List.fold_left`, which I think is a little easier.

The essence of `fold_left` is to figure out a function that does one step of your computation. The function takes the accumulated answer so far, and one new element of the list. The return value is the new accumulated answer. If you can define such a function, you can fold it over the input list to get your full answer.

One way to look at this is that your function is exactly what would appear as the body of a `for` statement. The body of a `for` also does one step of a computation.

Let's say I want to add a list of integers. So my desired function takes the accumulated answer so far (an int), the next value from the list (an int), and it returns the new accumulated answer (the sum of the two ints). So the function to be folded looks like this:

```
let foldme a b = a + b
```

If you fold this over a list of ints you get the sum:

```
# let foldme a b = a + b;;
val foldme : int -> int -> int = <fun>
# List.fold_left foldme 0 [3; 5; 7; 11];;
- : int = 26
```

If you wanted to reverse a list, you want a function that takes the answer so far (reverse of the first part of the list), and a new element of the list, and returns the reverse with the new value added at the beginning. So the function you want looks like this:

```
let foldme2 a b = b :: a
```

If you fold this over a list, you get the reverse of the list:

```
# let foldme2 a b = b :: a;;
val foldme2 : 'a list -> 'a -> 'a list = <fun>
# List.fold_left foldme2 [] [4; 5; 6; 7];;
- : int list = [7; 6; 5; 4]
```

If you can figure out a function that does one step of your computation, you can figure out how to do folds. It does take a while to get good at it.

Comment: Can you please explain fold_right and fold_left or direct me to a thorough explanation of them? I've tried looking at multiple resources and they have all confused me.

Comment: for instance I tried doing this let unzip : ('a * 'b) list -> 'a list * 'b list = map (fun (x,y) -> x::[])] :: [map(fun (x,y) -> y::[]) but I realized it just appends two lists and returns c' list >_>

Comment: Don't use `::` use `,` to make a pair.

Comment: Excellent write up, thank you! Okay so if I try to just make a function that splits a tuple


let splitTuple (a,b) = ((a::[]) , (b::[]))

bam, that works.

then if I try to incorporate it in this unzip, it fails :(

let unzip : ('a * 'b) list -> 'a list * 'b list = fold_left (fun (a,b) -> ( a::[], b::[])) ([], []) [(1,2); (2,3); (3,4)];;

Comment: Your code doesn't do an incremental step of computation. You need to *add* the new values to an accumulated answer. `let splitTuple (accuma, accumb) (a, b) = ...`.

Answer (score 2):

```
let f (l,s) (x,y) = (x::l,y::s);;
let unzip l = List.fold_left f ([],[]) (List.rev l);;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `List.map` twice: once with `fst` and once with `snd`. However, I suggest you take the time to understand `List.fold_right` and `List.fold_left` because they're useful in many contexts.