# OCaml update value through iteration of a list

Tags: ocaml

I was wondering how I can update the value of a variable through the iteration of a list. For example, let's say I want to keep track of the number of variables of a list. I could do something like

```
let list = [1;2;3;4;5]
let length = 0 in
    let getCount elmt = 
        length = length+1 in 
    List.iter getCount list
```

but I get the error `This expression has type 'a -> bool` which makes sense because at `length = length+1` I am comparing using `=`. How should I update the value of length?

EDIT:

I tried

```
let wordMap =
let getCount word = 
    StringMap.add word (1000) wordMap in 
List.fold_left getCount StringMap.empty wordlist;;
```

but it doesn't know what wordMap is in getCount function...

Comment: Why are'nt you using `List.length list` to get the length of your list ?

Comment: This is just an example. For my actual function, instead of length I have a map that I'm using to store the occurrences of elements, which means I have to do Map.empty to get an empty map, and then I have to update the map by adding to it. I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: In OCaml, generally you should avoid mutations if you can: do not use a mutable `ref` counter but use `List.fold_left` or `fold_right` for this kind of problem.

Comment: Yeah I understand, that's why I wanted to know how a "ocaml/functional" approach would try the problem... :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@PatJ gives a good discussion. But in real code you would just use a fold. The purpose of a fold is precisely what you ask for, to maintain some state (of any type you like) while traversing a list.

Learning to think in terms of folds is a basic skill in functional programming, so it's worth learning.

Once you're good at folds, you can decide on a case-by-case basis whether you need mutable state. In almost all cases you don't.

(You can definitely use a fold to accumulate a map while traversing a list.)

Comment: OK! Thank you. I knew that I had an error in my thinking somewhere, I just wasn't sure where...

Comment: I made a quick edit, wondering if you could take a look for me? Added my attempt at using fold...

Comment: The state is maintained through parameters, not a global. The function to be folded takes *two* parameters. If you use `fold_left`, the first is the current state (the map) and the second is the next element of the list. It returns a new map. Your code tries to use a global value; that doesn't work (it's immutable).

Comment: I wrote a few SO answers about folds recently. Here's one where I tried to give the intuition with simple examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32792844/recursion-using-ocaml-and-unzip/32792862?s=5%7C0.0000#32792862

Answer (score 3):

You have several ways to do this.

The simpler way (often preferred by beginners coming from the imperative world) is to use a reference. A reference is a variable you can legally mutate.

```
let length l =
 let count = ref 0 in
 let getCount _ = (* _ means we ignore the argument *)
  count := !count + 1
 in
 List.iter getCount l;
 !count
```

As you can see in here, `!count` returns the value currently in the reference and `:=` allows you to do the imperative update.

**But you should not write that code**

Yeah, I'm using bold, this is how serious I am about it. Basically, you should avoid using references when you can rely on pure functional programing. That is, when there are no side-effects.

So how do you modify a variable when you are not allowed to? That's where recursion comes in. Check this:

```
let rec length l =
 match l with
 | [] -> 0
 | _::tl -> 1 + length tl
```

In that code, we no longer have a `count` variable. Don't worry, we'll get it back soon. But you can see that just by calling length again, we can assign a new value `tl` to the argument `l`. Yet it is pure and considered a better practice.

Well, almost.

The last code has the problem of recursion: each call will add (useless) data to the stack and, after being through the list, will do the additions. We don't want that.

However, function calls can be optimized if they are *tail calls*. As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) can explain to you:

> a tail call is a subroutine call performed as the final action of a
>   procedure.

In the later code, the recursive call to `length` isn't a tail call as `+` is the final action of the function. The usual trick is to use an accumulator to store the intermediate results. Let's call it `count`.

```
let rec length_iterator count l =
 match l with
 | [] -> count
 | _::tl -> length_iterator (count+1) tl
in
let length l = length_iterator 0 l
```

And now we have a neat, pure, and easy-to-optimize code that calculates the length of your list.

So, to answer the question as stated in the title: iterate with a (tail-)recursive function and have the updatable variables as arguments of this function.

Comment: Thanks Pat. I actually have the same optimized tail recursion as you, but I asked this question because I had something else I was trying to do so I was trying to learn the concept through an easier example. For my actual function, instead of length I have a map that I'm using to store the occurrences of elements, which means I have to do Map.empty to get an empty map, and then I have to update the map by adding to it. I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: @jstnchng, I'm not sure I understand your question. If you want to iterate through a map then, as @Jeffrey Scofield stated, `fold` is your friend (basically, it does the traversal and you just write the argument update). If not, please update your question with code samples so we can see your precise problem.

Comment: I think like both you and Jeffrey mentioned, I should try fold first. Thank you for your help, I will update with results!

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to get the length of the list, just use the function provided by List Module: `List.length`. Otherwise, variables in OCaml are never mutable and what you're trying to do is illegal in OCaml and not functional at all. But if you really have to update a value, consider using `ref`(for more info: http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2011sp/recitations/rec10.htm).